# Monotone for the Git user?

Tags: git, monotone

I'm pretty used to `git` by now, and I'm about to start contributing to a project that uses Monotone (`mtn`).  I could just use the export system to convert to git locally, but I figured

- learning another DVCS wouldn't be too hard
- learning is Good For Me<sup>TM</sup>
- it'd be easier to coordinate with other devs if we were all using the same DVCS

Is there a guide or tutorial for `mtn` aimed at experienced `git` users?  Or can anyone here give me the 25¢ tour?

Comment: I can give you a small tour if you're still interested. Sorry if I noticed this message so late; I'll be watching this tag using RSS now. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monotone being one of the rare DVCS that [pre-date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_%28software%29) git, I'm afraid it is going to be hard to find something better tailored to git users than the [tutorial](http://www.monotone.ca/docs/Tutorial.html).